# Combine 3 1TB drives via LVM and then pair in RAID 1 with 1 3TB drive

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm

I have 3 1TB drives I want to combine via LVM and the create a RAID 1 with a separate 3TB drive.Can this be done? All disks are just data storage in a home server, filesystem is on separate disks.

Comment: I see no reason why this cannot be done. You would have more points of failure than a more usual 2 matching drive setup. I’d guess you wouldn’t get exactly 3TB out of the 3 drive LVM so you might need to match what you get on the 3TB drive. Nothing to lose by trying it.

Comment: Cool thanks. Kind of what I was thinking; both it should be feasible, and matching sizes would be a minor hassle.